# How to execute url which has xml data as query parameter through Apache HttpClient?

Tags: java, http-post, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I have a XML like below which is stored as a String in `xmlData` variable and I need to pass this String to my url in `client_data` variable -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ClientData
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.google.com model.xsd" 
 xmlns="http://www.google.com"> 
    <client id="100">
        <clock>
                <for>
                    <etc>val(tery) = 1</etc>
                    <while><![CDATA[val(tery)  < 20]]></while>
                </for>
        </clock>
    </model>
</ClientData>
```

Below is the URL I am hitting on the browser by URL encoding `client_data` value to get the response back and it works fine.

```
http://localhost:8080/test_tmp?max_time=30&users=1000&client_data=<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ClientData
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.google.com model.xsd" 
 xmlns="http://www.google.com"> 
    <client id="100">
        <clock>
                <for>
                    <etc>val(tery) = 1</etc>
                    <while><![CDATA[val(tery)  < 20]]></while>
                </for>
        </clock>
    </model>
</ClientData>
```

Now I need to do the same thing through `Apache HttpClient`. What is the best way to do this?

I have got below code but not sure whethere there is any better way to do this? Is there anything I can improve on or some better way of doing it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String xmlData = getXMLData();
    String url = generateURL(xmlData);

    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(request);

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
    }

    // prints response
    System.out.println(response);       
}

private static String generateURL(final String clientData) {
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
    url.append("http://localhost:8080/test_tmp?max_time=30&users=1000&client_data=");
    url.append(URLEncoder.encode(clientData, "UTF-8"));

    return url.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I don't think you want to try and pass XML through your URI.   There are several things to consider.  One, some servers will block long URIs (Google first result: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E414.html ).  Next, you would want to "encode" the URI so it escapes all of your chars that are not ready to be passed raw.

Consider doing a "POST" with the xml the body of the HTTP message.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. If I am sending POST request, then my web service has to handle that POST request right? Also, can you provide an example how can I send POST request through HttpClient?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could make your request without using `Apache HttpClient`, you could just open stream by url

This is how you could pass XML in the query parameter and read the response as stream:

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder("http://localhost:8080/test_tmp")
    .addParameter("max_time", "30")
    .addParameter("users", "1000")
    .addParameter("client_data", xmlData)
    .build();

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(uri.toURL().openStream())
);
```

If you insist on using `Apache HttpClient`, then code could look like:

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder("http://localhost:8080/test_tmp")
    .addParameter("max_time", "30")
    .addParameter("users", "1000")
    .addParameter("client_data", xmlData)
    .build();

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent())
);
```